# Custom $_SESSION expires too early

Tags: php, session

In my custom Wordpress theme I want to keep some user's data stored over time (let's say 5 days) using $_SESSION variable.

At a certain point in my theme I do a very simple thing:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_data'] = $my_object;
```

`session_start()` may be useless because it should have been called by Wordpress core before my script, but that's not the point. The problem is that my custom data gets erased after few hours, even if I change it to:

```
session_start();
session_set_cookie_params(432000);
$_SESSION['my_data'] = $my_object;
```

I'm wondering how the $_SESSION variable is managed by the Wordpress code and if there is a way to extend its validity... or better to increase the validity by 5 days to just my data, that is always stored in `$_SESSION['my_data']`

Comment: Session cookies are destroyed when the browser is closed. Why do you expect yours to behave differently?

Comment: `Session cookies are destroyed when the browser is closed`, really? Because if I simply close everything in the client and reopen the page after, say, one hour, the $_SESSION is still as I left it. "Invalidation" happens if I wait _more hours_.
Anyway, as you see I don't have such great knowledge about PHP sessions... should I use instead [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)?

Answer (score 1):

One tip from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

> Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and **before** session_start() is called.

You are calling it after.